# PHP preg_match if pattern is a variable

Tags: php, preg-match

If the pattern is a variable in preg_match, it's correct this syntax for use the delimiters?

```
if (!preg_match("/{$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]}/",$variable)){
  .......
}
```

Comment: Make sure to escape dynamic regex.

Comment: Is this actually the regex you're using, or a simplified example?

Comment: Are you wanting to replace the exact string `{$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]}` with the contents of `$variable`, or are you wanting to replace the value of `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]` enclosed in swirly brackets, with the value of `$variable` ?

Comment: @Waleed Khan is actually the regex that I use

Comment: @DanielePalombetta Then why not something like `strstr` or `strpos` that doesn't use regexes at all?

Comment: @druciferre I'm not replace but compare if $variable is different from $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]

Comment: @Waleed Khan because before it was
if (!eregi(........))
so I've substituted with preg_match, but I think you're right!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right way to handle this is by using [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/preg_quote) to make sure characters with a special meaning in regular expressions are properly escaped:

```
$pattern = '/' . preg_quote($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], '/') . '/';
if (!preg_match($pattern, $variable)) {
}
```

Of course, this in itself is not a very useful expression, because you can also write this:

```
if (strpos($variable, $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) === false) {
}
```

Comment: Very kind of you for this explanation